# Similar but slightly different JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have two very similar functions that exist mainly for syntactic sugar.

```
deactivate = (el, seek) -> el.find(seek).removeClass("active")
activate = (el, seek) -> el.find(seek).addClass("active")
```

This allows me to write, for example:

```
activate $("#something"), ".child"
```

Using the above purely as an example, ignoring any logical errors with the JavaScript itself… how could this be refactored to be more dry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use js' bracket notation for this task

```
alter = (el, seek, method) -> el.find(seek)[method + "Class"]("active")
#use like this:
alter $("#something"), ".child", "add"
```

However, your situation doesn't really call for DRYness. Your method names make more sense than `alter`, or whichever name you may choose.

Comment: You could just use your `alter` function as a stepping stone for the definitions of `activate`/`deactivate` become more DRY: `deactivate = (el, seek) -> alter el, seek, "remove"` `activate = (el, seek) -> alter el, seek, "add"` (Disclamer: I don't use CoffeScript)

Comment: @RoToRa Correct, and you can also do it the other way around: Store `activate` and `deactivate` on an object, and pass which one you want as an argument to `alter`: `containingObject[method]("active")`

Comment: Thank you. I think the syntactic benefit of my initial functions outweigh the benefit of making the code more DRY. I was just wondering if there was something I was missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine. I would only suggest a more complex solution only if this pattern happens more often.

For example, if you want to refactor to allow for other class names you can do something like this:

```
adder   = clsName -> (el, seek) -> el.find(seek).removeClass(clsName)
remover = clsName -> (el, seek) -> el.find(seek).addClass(clsName)

activate   = adder 'active'
deactivate = remover 'active'
```